# Transaction not rolling back as expected using the mssql module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, transactions, tedious

I actually found the answer to this question already, and just want to document my finding.

Here's what causes the problem:

```
let transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);
await transaction.begin();
await pool.request (transaction).query (" *** SOME SQL *** ");
await transaction.rollback();
```

The transaction won't roll back at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem, I ended up using `new sql.Request (transaction)` instead of `pool.request (transaction)`. The codes will look like the following:

```
let transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);
await transaction.begin();
await new sql.Request (transaction).query (" *** SOME SQL *** ");
await transaction.rollback();
```

I did not dig deeper to find out the actual mechanism of how the connection pool works, but it appears that unlike the `sql.Request` class constructor, the `pool.request` method does not take a **transaction** parameter (someone who has the knowledge please tell us if this is true).

**UPDATE**

I went back and check the **mssql** module's source codes and found that there is a **request** method in the **Transaction** class, so another solution is to do:

```
let transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);
await transaction.begin();
await transaction.request().query (" *** SOME SQL *** ");
await transaction.rollback();
```